# How do I determine segment errors displayed by valgrind？

Tags: valgrind

Processes running directly and starting through gdb are normal. However when I run it under valgrind, it will crash quickly showing segment errors(without any else information). Is there any good way to locate the problem code?

I try to run it in gdb for many times and it can run for a long time without crash.[image]

Comment: What OS? What architecture? What compiler? Which version of Valgrind? What output _do_ you get from Valgrind?

Comment: OS: CentOS7.6
architecture: x86
compiler: g++7
Valgrind version: 3.21.0

Comment: When it crash, only "segment error". In log , there are some possible memory leak

Comment: Edit you answer and give the Valgrind output. You can also try using verbose (v) and debug (-d) output, but it will be too long to post here. If you can, also post your source code. Without more information nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: There are many outputs (about 1MB). But when it crash, only "segment fault". Today I retry it without the arg "track-origins", and I didn't see crash.
I will try using verbose (v) and debug (-d) output tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: I find it won't crash when I remove the arg "--track-origins=yes".

Comment: That's of no use to anyone trying to help you. We don't have your computer or test exe. I've used track-origins extensively without problems. Either post more information or consider following the steps in README_DEVELOPERS, part of the Valgrind distribution, on debugging Valgrind.